# Is there an offline Web app for editing videos

Tags: offline, video-editing, progressive-web-application

If I want to cut a video without native, installed software, I go to google and search for "online video cutter". A bunch of great options come up.

The downside is that the video file needs to be uploaded to the server, which for large files can take a while.

Is it possible to build a fully functional offline web app that would serve as a video cutter (or even a full blown editor), without making use of a server?

My question is really two-fold:

1. Is it possible to achieve this?
2. Does something like this exist already?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*is it possible to achieve this?*"? Because of course it is possible, no?

Comment: What do you mean by offline

Comment: "offline" and "web app" are very close to be antonyms. Not sure what you're exactly trying to achieve either. If something should work locally without internet access then the web application will have to install itself in your system. Or use 3rd party tools like Docker. How else would it function? And if you instead meant just "without the need to upload the file" then that's completely different from "offline". But in that case how is the application supposed to know what the video file is?

Comment: So TLDR: your request seems impossible and I'm not sure why you want to avoid installing software that would just do it.

Comment: The thing you may be confusing is that "offline & online editing" are terms unrelated to 'the internet' & came long before. Offline editing does not touch the original footage, only copies. in this modern data age & with digital video the term is somewhat redundant, but the modern equivalent is that you edit proxy media - a low-quality copy - then when finished, the software then matches those edits & generates a final video from your original media [online editing]. Wherever that is done, first it must be given the full-quality media. If that is 'on the web' then you must upload it all first.

Comment: Offline Web app make not much sence. The app can be offline or on the Web.

Comment: @Destroy666 To avoid installation there are portable software.

Comment: Ok. To explain: I put a tag called progressive-web-app, which is a website that you visit, that downloads files locally so that you can revisit the website even without Internet connection, with the functionality still there even though you are offline. So it's basically an offline website which doesn't need to be installed. I'm talking about a website that would work totally offline and would edit videos. Clipchamp as bindestrich mentioned is a great example! Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: I don't want a portable software. I want a progressive webapp that works offline

Comment: Oh oops, I missed that tag, should have just included PWA in the title. But regardless, PWAs are "installed" in your system, or downloaded rather, when you first visit them or click to install.

Answer (score 1):

1. yes.
2. clipchamp by microsoft is such an example. https://clipchamp.com/en/

"Simply head to the Microsoft Store, install our web app, and start creating your video projects."

On my windows 11 installation Clip champ was suggested to me instead of the old video editor included in the image viewer.

Comment: I didn't go far enough through their page to figure out how you can do this without uploading your footage…

Comment: Great example! Do you know of any free open source software though?

Comment: This software is not usable w/o internet just for the record

Answer (score 1):

[Motionity](https://motionity.notion.site/motionity/Get-started-with-Motionity-bc2a2017670d4ec6a44d5ff760ca4656) by Alyssa X is another option.

It's [open-source](https://github.com/alyssaxuu/motionity) and stores files locally.

https://github.com/alyssaxuu/motionity/blob/main/preview.gif

That said, it's still pretty new, and limited in its features. You won't get the same editing experience in web based apps that you could get in proper desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a web app, but Kdenlive is a pretty solid, open source video editing app that uses local files: https://kdenlive.org/

Comment: This does not answer the question, since the question was about a webapp (basically an HTML+CSS+JavaScript browser based software)

Comment: @Dave is there a particular reason why it needs to be a web app?

Answer (score 0):

The closest to what you requested is [LosslessCut](https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut). The UI is fully based on the web (HTML, JavaScript, running inside Electron), but it also uses `ffmpeg` to perform the actual video edits. Thus, it's not really a web app that you can run from the web.

Someone could try forking that project and adding `ffmpeg` compiled to web assembly, so it potentially could run directly from and within the browser. I'm not aware of any such project.